# In a long set of calculations, how can I avoid "The instance of entity type 'Person' cannot be tracked ..."

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, automapper, dbcontext

I am working on a console application that will execute a single transaction comprised of a complex set of business logic. There will be multiple services called during this transaction and it is almost certain that any given entity will be updated in the repository multiple times.

I am using dependency injection to inject my repositories, services, dbcontext, and unit of work wherever they are needed.  In its very early stage, the transaction looks like this:

```
using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider
        .GetRequiredService<FantasySimulationDBContext>();

    using (var dbContextTransaction = 
        dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            var flowControllerService = 
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IFlowControllerService>();
            flowControllerService.IncrementTime();
            flowControllerService.IncrementTime();
            dbContextTransaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

I only call flowControllerService.IncrementTime() twice to illustrate the type of functionality I want to have.  I want this to be a possibility, and it currently is not.

The IncrementTime method in my service looks like this:

```
    public void IncrementTime()
    {

        //do a bunch of stuff to a "Person" object
        _personRepository.UpdatePerson(person);
        _unitOfWork.Complete();
    }
```

The PersonRepository maps my domain models back to persistence models and updates them in the dbContext.  It looks like this:

```
public class PersonRepository: IPersonRepository
{
    private readonly FantasySimulationDBContext _dbContext;
    private IMapper _mapper;

    public PersonRepository(FantasySimulationDBContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _dbContext = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    ...
    public void UpdatePerson(Person person)
    {
        var mappedPerson = _mapper.Map<PersistenceModels.Person>(person);
        _dbContext.People.Update(mappedPerson);
    }  
}
```

What ends up happening is the first call to IncrementTime works fine. However, the second call causes the following exception to occur: "The instance of entity type 'Person' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked."  I know it is happening because when I save the first time, the "Person" that I saved is still in the dbContext's changetracker, and then I'm re-using the same dbContext in the second call to IncrementTime.  So when the person repository tries to update the same person a second time, I get the exception because it's already in the change tracker.

I could detach everything each time after I commit the unit of work, but I never see that in anyone else's code, so I'm assuming I just have some fundamental aspect of my entire process wrong.  So what is the correct way to handle the problem, or barring that, what misstep have I taken in designing this?

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to do this from what I can tell (other than the ways you've said: detach, etc). First is you can hold onto the entity and update that instead of the 'DTO' you are using. The other would be to fetch the instance of the `Person` like this:

```
var personModel = _dbContext.People.Find(person.ID);
_mapper.Map(person, personModel);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

That way you are always just using the single instance that your `DBContext` is already holding onto and tracking.

Comment: I've been trying the second method you listed a bit, but as far as I can tell, it marks any objects in nested collections of Person as "Added" in the change tracker which causes all sorts of problems when it tries to save.  I tried using AutoMapper.Collection to solve this issue, but I can't get it to work in dot net core.